# Fiware pep-proxy: Uploaded zip file's size changes when uploaded with PEP standing between client and REST API

Tags: proxy, django-rest-framework, fiware

I created REST web service using DjangoRestFramework that accepts some inputs and a zip file.
When i don't use PEP Proxy as a gateway between client(javascript app) and this web service, there are no problems, all data including zipped file are correct. But when I put PEP Proxy in the middle, my zip file size increases about 30MB and i get corrupted zip file, and the other data is ok.
Error message:

```
Zip file size: 73106015 bytes, number of entries: 1
error [/tmp/tmp1_GLtj.upload]:  missing 3949084193 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [/tmp/tmp1_GLtj.upload]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

And real size of this file is **39055691 bytes.**
How can PEP proxy change file that is being uploaded?

Comment: The only thing PEP Proxy does in the requests is to add several headers with user information. It should no change the body (where I assume you are sending the file). You can compare the request before and after passing though the PEP in order to check if there is something wrong.